# How to update a value in a cvs file through a mouse click on highcharts graphs

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv, highcharts

I want to update my cvs file through a mouse click on a graph, like I create a graph by reading a data from the same cvs file and when I get a graph what I want is that whenever I click on a point it make that point equal to zero on y-axis and update the corresponding value in a cvs file equal to 0.

Please can someone help. Here is my code which can take values from cvs file but is not updating but the same code works fine if I take hard coded series of an array.
Don't understand why isn't these plot options working.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Highcharts Example</title>


<!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
<script type="text/javascript"         src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/highcharts.js"></script>
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/excanvas.compiled.js"></script>
<![endif]-->


<!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on document ready -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


var options = {

chart: {
renderTo: 'container',
defaultSeriesType: 'line'},

title: { text: 'Output'},

xAxis: { categories: []},

yAxis: {
title: { text: 'Units'} },

plotOptions: {
series: { cursor: 'pointer',
point: {
events: { click: function() {
var y = this.item(y);
var x = this.x;

chart.series[0].data[x].update(y -= y);} } } },
series: []
};


$.get('testFile.csv', function(data) {
// Split the lines
var lines = data.split('\n');
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
var items = line.split(',');
var series = {
data: []
}; 
$.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
series.data.push(parseFloat(item));

});

options.series.push(series); });

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 1400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch click point action http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click and then use get new value from csv by ajax and use update() function http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update()

Comment: I am already using plotOptions and update() function in my code but it doesn't work. I guess I don't understand how to get particular value(the value which I am trying to change) from cell of csv file. Please see that particular part of code and help me in modifying it.

Comment: This is what I was supposed to do in code above                 plotOptions: { series: { cursor: 'pointer', point: { events: { click: function() { this.update(0);} } } },